# She expressed the wish that God [might] bless America

Tags: optative-mood

A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (Quirk et al.) says:

> **14.34 The subjunctive and modal auxiliaries in indirect speech**
> There is no indirect speech construction for the optative subjunctive (*cf* 11.39), but when it is used to express a wish the construction with *may* (with a possible backshift to *might*) is sometimes a near-equivalent:
>
> > 'God *bless* America!' she said.
> > ~ She expressed the wish that God *might bless* America.

In this "near-equivalent", *might* seems to be used to denote the same optative meaning as *May* in *May God bless America!*. Am I right about this?

If so, why would you need such an optative meaning of *might* when you already have the noun "wish", which denotes the optative meaning?

For example, I think it's entirely possible to use *would* instead in the near-equivalent:

> She expressed the wish that God *would bless* America.

Comment: Take a look at Fillmore's classic ["May We Come In?"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf) to see about the various senses of _may_ in English.

Comment: If you don't know how to answer a question, you shouldn't label it as "opinion-based" and try to close it. Instead, you should upvote the question so those who are more knowledgeable about the topic can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

> In this "near-equivalent", might seems to be used to denote the same optative meaning as May in May God bless America!. Am I right about this?

Yes. That said, as CGEL notes, this is only *sometimes* true, because "might" does not necessarily have an optative meaning in this context. The word "might" here can just express possibility: "She feared that God might curse America" is also valid.

> If so, why would you need such an optative meaning of might when you already have the noun "wish", which denotes the optative meaning?

In this context, the two are indeed redundant; "would" and "might" would both be correct here, though perhaps "might" reinforces the optative connotation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142341/discussion-on-answer-by-alphabet-she-expressed-the-wish-that-god-might-bless-a).